# Elasticsearch total shard count impact on an index search speed

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search

I know that the shard count and size has a significant impact on the search performance (speed) and cluster recovery.

Does the total number of shard count impact the search speed? Let me simplify it assume I have 5 indices with 5 primary shards each and I am searching in **indice1** only and assume it return me the response in 500ms. **Will this be same (500ms) if I add 5 more indices?** I know the recovery time would increase but not sure about a specific indice search performance.

Any help would be highly appricated.

Answer (score 2):

Common sense would imply that searching on more data takes longer, however,
it's impossible to answer without also knowing:

- the number of nodes (more nodes can parallelize searches on several shards)
- their hardware specs (ram and cpu play a role in how many concurrent searches can happen on a single node)
- if any write operations also happen at the same time (taking resources away from search threads)
- etc...

The best you can do is to actually create a test case (using e.g. [Rally](https://github.com/elastic/rally)) and test this on your own infrastructure.

Comment: thanks for your input. Sure I will update my question.

Comment: I am only searching in one index and its shards and data remains the same. What is the impact on this same index searching if I add 2 more indexes but those are not part of the search.

Comment: If the other indexes are not part of the search, there's no impact, or a very marginal one

Comment: Sorry for the delay Val, we are still testing the workload.

Comment: Great, let us know if you need more help